# jquery masonry animating items

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have implemented jquery masonry and played with it a bit.

Here's my work: http://jsfiddle.net/jackoverflow/JDAmS/

As you can see, clicking "expand" will animate the item having a width of "300px"
and collapses back to it's normal width on "collapse" click.

All is working okay EXCEPT when clicking the "first item" which collapses all the items.

can someone help me please?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's wrong? It seems to work correctly for me (Chrome).

Comment: @jimw: compare expansion of the first and the second divs. Reproduced in latest chrome

Comment: Ah, do you mean the fact that expanding the first div pushes all the others into a vertical stack under it?

Comment: Interesting. It works if you have an empty `li.story` at the beginning: http://jsfiddle.net/Ar4s9/7/, not that that helps you much. More poking...

Comment: And a simpler test-case: http://jsfiddle.net/Ar4s9/16/.

Comment: thanks man. why didn't i think of that. yeah, adding an empty li.story at the beginning resolved it BUT i'm still wondering why it ain't working as other divs are behaving. :)

Answer (score 1):

From [the Masonry docs - Help - First item breaks grid](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/help.html#first_item_breaks_grid):

> If you run into an issue where you re-size the first item, and all the rest of the items no longer fit together in the grid, you most likely need to set columnWidth option. Without columnWidth set, Masonry will use the width of the first item for the size of its columns.

```
$('#container').masonry({
  columnWidth: 220
});
```